# Method overloading in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.Math;
class Squr
{
    public static void main ()
    {        
        Squr square = new Squr();
        System.out.println ("square root of 10 : " + square.mysqrt(10));
        System.out.println (" Square root of 10.4 : "+ square.mysqrt(10.4));         
    }

    int mysqrt ( int x)
    {
        return Math.sqrt(x);
    }

    double mysqrt (double y)
    {
        return Math.sqrt(y);
    }
}
```

When we compile it then it's giving error

```
possible loss of precision
found :double
required :int
```

I have written this program for calculating square root of `int` or `double` type values by method overloading concept.

How can I fix my error so I can find the square root of an `int` and a `double`?

Comment: question is i m trying to find out square root of int as well as double type value...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is anything to do with method overloading - it's actually quite simple.

`Math.sqrt()` returns a `double`, but in your first class method, you're trying to return this directly from a method that returns int.  This would be a lossy conversion, and you'd need to perform it manually.

In particular - when you call `mysqrt(5)`, which integer do you expect the answer to be?  `2`?  `3`?  Some "warning, not a whole number" value like `-1`? I suspect that perhaps you meant to *return* `double` for both methods, and differ only in the type of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

My eclipse gives:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int

Whatever the message is, you fix this by: `return (int) Math.sqrt(x);`

This has nothing to do with overloading though.

By the way, a square root of an integer can be `double`, so by having a return type `int` you are truncating possibly important information.

Hence I'd advise for simply using `Math.sqrt(..)` without making any additional methods. If you need the whole part, you can use `Math.floor(..)` or `Math.round(..)`

Comment: Casting the return of Math.sqrt() to int is more of a bodge than a fix. As others have stated, this approach results in a loss of precision. If he just wants the whole number, this should be handled formally, before the method's return statement.

Comment: @Mikavel - true it leads to loss of precision, but I assumed the return type being fixed to `int` is "by requirement". I'll clarify

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29

returns double. Casting in int will loose precision. Don't you think so?

JLS has something to say on conversions. See this http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html

> The following 22 specific conversions on primitive types are called the narrowing primitive conversions:
>
> ```
> * short to byte or char
> * char to byte or short
> * int to byte, short, or char
> * long to byte, short, char, or int
> * float to byte, short, char, int, or long
> * double to byte, short, char, int, long, or float
> ```
>
> **Narrowing conversions may lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision.**